# Convert Relation to 3rd Normal Form and BCNF Check Work

Tags: database, relational-database, relationship, database-normalization, bcnf

I am trying to convert this relation into 3rd Normal Form and BCNF.

Given a relation R(A1, A2, A3, A4), with three FDs

A2, A3 → A4 ;

A3, A4 → A1;

A1, A2→ A3.

Provide the 3NF and BCNF form of the schema and explain why.

I remember doing this but am a but rusty.

Here is my start.

I split on the functional dependency A2, A3-> A4

Thus that creates:

R1(A2, A3, A4)

R2(A1, A2, A3)

Since there aren't any more functional or transitive dependencies, this should be in 3NF.

My questions are first if this approach is correct.

Second since both the keys (A2, A3) for R1 and (A1, A2) for R2 are both composite keys, wouldn't this be in BCNF as well?

I was wondering if this is true, and if not what would be the BCNF for this relation?

Please let me know if you need any further information.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi. Please get a reference text & name it & follow it. You want us to check your work--against what? Even if we were willing to rewrite your reference we don't know which of many ways of organizing the overall goal you are following. Give every *definition* & *algorithm* you use. Right away: What does "with three FDs" mean? If it has those 3 it doesn't only have those three. Do they maybe form a *cover*? Eg "transitive dependency" means "transitive FD" so no FDs makes "no transitive dependencies" redundant. And there are other FDs--eg always trivial ones. Eg why did you split so? Etc etc.

Comment: Now that you have an answer, in which the reasoning is correct, does it really help you to do the next normalization? (Even when it says "since", it gives some fragments re justification but not the full rule(s)/theorem(s)/fact(s) or definitions or algorithms it's applying. And it doesn't give an overall algorithm.) And has your work been checked? And so have you asked the right question? (Rhetorical.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the fact that a schema is in 3NF if every determinant is a superkey or each determinate attribute is prime, the schema is already in 3NF. In fact, the only candidate keys of `R` are `{A1, A2}` and `{A2, A3}`. `A2` must be in every key, since it does not appear in any right hand side of the dependencies. If you add to it `A1` you can discover that you obtain a candidate key since `A1, A2` determines all the attributes, and the same if you try to add `A3` to `A2`. This is not true adding `A4`, `A1`, `A2` and `A3` are prime attributes and no functional dependency violates the 3NF.

Given the fact that a schema is in BCNF if every non-trivial dependency has a determinat which is a superkey, your schema is not in BCNF for the dependency `A3, A4 → A1`, since`{A3, A4}` is not a superkey.

Applying the “analysis” algorithm to produce a decomposed schema in BNCF, you can use the dependency `A3, A4 → A1` to decompose in BCNF, and this produces two relations:

```
R1 (A1, A3, A4) (with candidate key {A3, A4})
R2 (A2, A3, A4) (with candidate key {A2, A3})
```

Both are in BCNF, so no further decomposition is necessary, but note that in this process the dependency `A1 A2 → A3` is lost.

Comment: Please see my comments on the question.

Comment: @philipxy, I've update the answer trying to be a little bit more descriptive.

Comment: The problem is the question is ill-posed. So you have given an answer with justification for post fragment "what would be the BCNF for this relation" but if you try to answer the actual question it involves the asker's assumptions & reasoning which just are not present in the post. Even the givens are ill-described. So as I say in my comments on the question they don't give enough info for their actual question to be answered & answering it wouldn't help them learn how to normalize & you are just answering a fragment of text from their question & in a way that doesn't direct them to learning.